# Does google app engine allow you to host server-side code?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, server, braintree

In order to integrate Google App Engine with Braintree, I require the ability to host server side code. Since I am not using my own server and instead Google App Engine and Firebase, I am puzzled as to how I can achieve this.

The Braintree support team says that "merchants that have successfully implemented Braintree with the platform" (platform meaning GAE). So clearly this is possible. Does anyone know of a way or of a service that the Google Cloud Platform offers to do this?

Comment: em, it's all about server-side code. choose any https://cloud.google.com/products/compute/

Comment: I have taken a look at the documentation and it seems a little complex for me (first app). Is there a good tutorial somewhere that could help me with compute engine?

Comment: appengine is 100% about server-side code. I think you have a lot of reading to do before you can ask a valid s.o. question about appengine.

Comment: Ok I will read up about it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform offers three options for your apps: App Engine standard environment, App Engine flexible environment, and Compute Engine.

With Compute Engine you can run anything you like with very few restrictions. App Engine environments have more restrictions, but many third-party libraries will work fine with no modifications.

Some third-party libraries require actions that App Engine either does not support at all (e.g., as of June 2016, streaming or responses over 32MB), or supports only in flexible environment. In such cases you can either use Compute Engine instances, or mix and match App Engine instances for your code with Compute Engine instances running third-party code.

NB: It appears from Braintree support team response that you should be able to run their code in your App Engine instance.

Comment: So it is not bad practice to use google cloud endpoints for most tasks and for third-party libraries that, like Braintree, require me to host code server side to use google compute engine. Right?

Comment: I am not familiar with Braintree, but it looks like you can simply include it in your own backend (https://github.com/braintree/braintree_java), so there is no need for Compute Engine instances.

Comment: Ahh yes you are right, I will give it a try and notify you on the result.